# Rails after_commit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

Has anyone implemented an `after_commit` hook in Rails ? I am not looking for model based after commits on update/create/etc, I want to be able to dynamically define a block that will be executed only if the current (top-most) transaction passes:

```
def remove_file
  current_transaction.after_commit do
    FileUtils.rm(file_path)
  end
end
```

Any idea if this has already been implemented, if it's going to be in rails 3.0 ?

Comment: Can't you do an after_save and check if your object has been updated ?

Comment: This would work if your transaction only wraps a single model's save operation. I need to wrap at least `Node + Version + Attachment`...

Answer (score 6):

Rails 3 provides after_commit/after_rollback callbacks: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/da840d13da865331297d5287391231b1ed39721b

In Rails 1 and 2 you can get the same functionality by using this gem: https://github.com/freelancing-god/after_commit

Answer (score 3):

This is in Rails core in Rails 3.

Documentation here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#M001117

Answer (score 2):

You won't see `after_commit` in Rails 3.0, at least not yet. You can apply a patch and see if it gets approved by the core team, but I doubt it would. This functionality remains much more functional outside of the Rails core, in a plugin.

You can try this plugin:

http://github.com/GUI/after_commit

Comment: I looked at the plugin, but it's a static way of defining after commits, and they are hooked on a single model from what I saw. I would prefere something that you add to the `after_commit` callbacks while saving.

Answer (score 2):

Since OP asked about dynamically setting code to be executed after a transaction is commited, after_commit does not solve his problem. Fortunately there is [after_commit_queue](https://github.com/shellycloud/after_commit_queue) gem that solves exactly this problem.

Using OP's example, the code would look like this:

```
include AfterCommitQueue

def remove_file
  run_after_commit do
    FileUtils.rm(file_path)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a lightweight after_commit plugin: [after_commit plugin](http://bit.ly/dbbveF)
that enables the following syntax:

```
def some_callback
  after_commit do
    # save file, expire cache, etc
  end
end
```

It's very lightweight but does the job.

Comment: Link doesn't work anymore and there is no code to show implementation.